# Recognizing and printing out only the vowels from a string

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm having a problem. I have to make a program in 8086 assembly to fill an array with a string, and then print out only the characters "a, A, e, E, i, I, o, O, u, U".
I have succeeded in printing out every character inside the array, but when I start adding conditions and jumps, my program just gets into an infinite loop :(

Here´s the whole code:

```
    org 100h

    jmp main

    ;messsages to be shown:

    msg1 db 'this is an example program.', 10, 13, 'made to show only the vocal letters of a string', 10, 13, 'write some words', 10, 10, 13, '$'
    msg2 db 10, 10, 13, 'your phrase:', 10, 10, 13, '$'

    ;variables

    aux db 0 
    vct dw 0

    ;program start

    main:
    lea dx, msg1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov cx, 20
    ingresarNumero:
    mov ah, 08h
    int 21h
    cmp al, 08h
    je borrar
    cmp al, 0Dh
    je enter 
    cmp al, 20h
    je enter
    mov ah, 0Eh
    int 10h
    mov ah, 0
    mov vct[si], ax
    inc si
    loop ingresarNumero

    ultimaPosicion:
    mov ah, 08h
    int 21h
    cmp al, 08h
    je borrar
    cmp al, 0Dh
    je finIngreso
    jmp ultimaPosicion

    borrar:
    cmp cx, 20
    je ingresarNumero
    mov ah, 0Eh
    int 10h
    mov al, 0
    int 10h
    mov al, 8
    int 10h
    pop ax
    inc cx
    dec si
    jmp ingresarNumero

    enter:
    cmp cx, 20
    je ingresarNumero
    jmp finIngreso

    finIngreso:

    lea dx, msg2
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    push cx
    mov cx, si
    mov si, 0
    superloop: 
    mov ax, vct[si]
    mov ah, 0Eh
    int 10h
    inc si
    loop superloop


    ret
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> vct dw 0
> ;program start
> main:
> ```

Because you didn't reserve enough memory for the characters you start overwriting your program! Change this definition (use bytes in stead of words):

```
vct db 100 dup (0)
```

When storing/retrieving to/from this memory use `AL` in stead of `AX`

```
mov vct[si], AL
inc si
```

and also

```
superloop: 
mov AL, vct[si]
mov ah, 0Eh
int 10h
```

---

Do you know *how* `push` and `pop` work?
Both `pop ax` and `push cx` in your program are meaningless!
Simply remove both.
Alternatively in the case of `push cx`, you could correct the code by adding the missing `pop cx`:

```
push cx
mov cx, si
mov si, 0
superloop: 
mov AL, vct[si]
mov ah, 0Eh
int 10h
inc si
loop superloop
pop cx               <<<<Add this
```

---

Your program uses the `SI` register without initializing it beforehand. If you're lucky the emulator EMU8086 will start up your program with just the right value in the `SI` register, but you can not count on that.
I sugggest you write:

```
mov si, 0
mov cx, 20
ingresarNumero:
```

---

You've chosen to output ASCII zero as the backspace character. The more usual choice here would have been ASCII 32. The nice thing is that you can actually write it as a space using `mov al, ' '`.

```
borrar:
cmp cx, 20
je ingresarNumero
mov ah, 0Eh        ;AL=8 at this point
int 10h
mov al, ' '        <<<< Better choice
int 10h
mov al, 8
int 10h
pop ax             <<<< Remove this entirely
inc cx
dec si
jmp ingresarNumero
```

---

> ```
> enter:
> cmp cx, 20
> je ingresarNumero
> jmp finIngreso
>
> finIngreso:
> ```

Jumping to a position directly below the `jmp` instruction is considered bad programming. In this code, if you didn't jump to *ingresarNumero*, you can simply fall through in the *finIngreso* section like so:

```
enter:
cmp cx, 20
je ingresarNumero
finIngreso:
```

---

> ```
> cmp al, 0Dh
> je enter 
> cmp al, 20h       <<<< Space character
> je enter
> ```

I do hope you realise that you've opted to finish input upon recieving a space character. This obviously means that your prompt message *'write some word**s**'* will not reflect your program's operation!

Comment: thank you so much! im not a fan of 8086, and it´s been hard for me to make this program. i didn´t realize about those mistakes, and thanks to you now i can continue!

Comment: Nice to see that my answer helped you on the way. Please consider to accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of it. This will earn you some extra points too. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)